# Print a column from a CSV files in Linux

Tags: linux, bash, csv

I have a very stupid question which I thought I could answer myself easyly...well I'm not able.

I have a file `";"` separated as following:

```
Grand Hotel  ;Yes;No availability;Dus ;11; . 130,00 ;No availability;500 mt from Arena;
```

I have to print it in a file (to move it into Excel) like following:

```
Grand Hotel
Yes
No Availability
...etc etc
```

So simple, I just can't find a very easy solution.
Since i'm working on a Debian Bash shell environment, I'm trying anything (bash script, awk, grep)...nothing works.
Please Help.
M.

Comment: $ cat FILENAME | while read line; do echo $line | tr ';' '\n'; echo ; done > filename.xls.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that your file is longer than one line, what will be the new *record* separator when all the fields are in separate lines?

This piece of awk will write each field on a new line, and add a blank line between each record.

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"; OFS="\n"; ORS="\n\n"} {$1=$1} 1'
```

The odd `$1=$1` bit is required to force awk to re-write $0 (i.e. the current record) with the new separators.

example:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=";"; OFS="\n"; ORS="\n\n"} {$1=$1} 1' << END
a;b;c
d;e;f
END
```

outputs

```
a
b
c

d
e
f
```

Answer (score 3):

So basically you want to convert a file with lines of the form `F1;F2;F3;...;FN` into:

```
 F1
 F2
 F3
 ...
 FN
```

We can use tr(1) to translate the semicolons into line breaks:

```
tr ';' '\n' < infile
```

Where "infile" is the name of the CSV input file.

Comment: also worth nothing that paste can be used to do the opposite: `paste -d ';' -s`

Answer (score 1):

How about `sed`:

```
echo '....' | sed 's/;/\n/g'
```

Comment: @MorganForever Check out Martin's answer as well, `tr(1)` should also work.